# Removing event listener of svg drag in a class

Tags: javascript, svg

I can drag, but I can't remove the drag. I read that there once I bind "this"
it passes a new function and I need to do some trickery with the local variable.

but can't seem to do it.

**Code:**

```
// import "./general";

class Home {
  constructor() {
    this.svgContainer = document.getElementById("svg-container");
    console.log(this.svgContainer);
    this.pt = this.svgContainer.createSVGPoint();
    this.circleSVG = document.getElementById("circleSVG");

  }

   startDrag() {
    this.svgContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveFunc.bind(this));
    this.circleSVG.addEventListener("mouseup", this.clearEvents.bind(this));
  }

  mouseMoveFunc(e) {
    console.log(this.pt)

    this.pt.x = e.clientX;
    this.pt.y = e.clientY;

    let svgPt = this.pt.matrixTransform(this.svgContainer.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    this.circleSVG.setAttribute("cx", svgPt.x);
    this.circleSVG.setAttribute("cy", svgPt.y);
  }

  clearEvents() {
    console.log(this.svgContainer.attributes)
    this.svgContainer.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveFunc);
    this.circleSVG.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.clearEvents);
  }
}

var home;
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  home = new Home();
});
```

here is the html:

```
<svg id="svg-container" width="500" height="500">
     <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" id="circleSVG" onmousedown="home.startDrag()"></circle>
</svg>
```

how can I solve this using a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you got no reference to the function that was attached on `mousemove`

To overcome you need to bind the `movemove` event inside the constructor with `this`

```
  constructor() {
    //.....
    this.mouseMoveFunc = this.mouseMoveFunc.bind(this);
  }
```

And also instead of your clear function use `mousedown` event to remove both `mouseup` and `mousemove` events

```js
class Home {
  constructor() {
this.svgContainer = document.getElementById("svg-container");
console.log(this.svgContainer);
this.pt = this.svgContainer.createSVGPoint();
this.circleSVG = document.getElementById("circleSVG");
this.mouseMoveFunc = this.mouseMoveFunc.bind(this);

  }

   startDrag() {
this.svgContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveFunc);
 this.circleSVG.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.startDrag);
//this.circleSVG.addEventListener("mouseup", this.clearEvents.bind(this));
  }
  
   stopDrag() {
   console.log(this.svgContainer);
   this.svgContainer.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.mouseMoveFunc);
this.circleSVG.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.startDrag);
  }

  mouseMoveFunc(e) {
console.log(this.pt)

this.pt.x = e.clientX;
this.pt.y = e.clientY;

let svgPt = this.pt.matrixTransform(this.svgContainer.getScreenCTM().inverse());
this.circleSVG.setAttribute("cx", svgPt.x);
this.circleSVG.setAttribute("cy", svgPt.y);
  }

}

var home;
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  home = new Home();
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg-container" width="500" height="500">
     <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" id="circleSVG" onmouseup="home.stopDrag()" onmousedown="home.startDrag()"></circle>
</svg>
```